# Cannot add rows to my data-bound dataGridview dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row

```
   RDP0 yeni = new RDP0();
        yeni.IPADDRESS = "1.1.1.1";
        yeni.PASSWORD = " 10akh0";
        yeni.NO = 8;
        yeni.CUSTID = 1000;
        testList.Add(yeni);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = testList;
```

I'm getting data-bound error therefore I cannot add rows. Any help would be great.
This is how I bound data to my dataGV:

```
        tm = new testModel();
        var query = from fe in tm.ERDP0 select fe;
        testList = query.ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = testList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `DataGridView` is data bound you cannot add new rows/columns to the `DataGridView` directly. But you could add a row to a `DataTable` which will update your `DataGridView` automatically.

```
DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
dt.Rows.Add("new row");
```

Or you could add the new row to your source list and then reset the DataSource:

```
testList.Add(youritem);
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = testList;
```

Comment: I'm gettin 1 more error now . "object reference not set to an instance of an object"
           ` DataTable dt = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;   
            using (DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow())
            {
                row.CreateCells(dataGridView2);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }                    
           
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt); `
@Roman

Comment: private List<RDP0> testList = new List<RDP0>();    rdp0 is the name of the table from my Database

Comment: with your help I find the solution to my problem thanks